# Is it possible to trigger HTML5 video playback with an event?

Tags: html, video

I know you can listen to events coming from the video, but it it possible to attach event to some element which is not the video, and it will trigger the playback?

I am looking for a simple solution for a custom "play" button over a video, on a mobile device, that will hide the native player's "play" button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use the <video> tag it does not come with a play button at all.

You need to specify <video controls> to get a "native player play button".

Here's a tutorial on building your own controls:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

[MediaElements.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) library could be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery:

```
$('#video_cont')[0].play()
```

will trigger the video to start playing